# Rearrangement algorithm

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, computer-arithmetic

I came across the following algorithm puzzle while interviewing for computer programmer job with a top internet giant.

There are $n=4$ bags with each bag able to carry a maximum of $k=500$ Kilogram weight before it breaks. Then there are many marbles which can attain any weight from $0.001$KG to $500$KG (probability of two marbles having exactly same weight is very low). Each of the $4$ bags is filled with enough marbles to weigh between $400$KG and $495$KG. Write an algorithm to move marbles across the bags so that with minimum number of moves the $4$ bags attain almost equal weight (as much as is possible). Generalize the solution for $n$ and $k$.

Any insight on what is the best algorithm to deal taking all edge cases into account.

Comment: Any insights from math veterans

Comment: Hint:  Virtual Machine Placement Algorithm

Comment: I don't understand when (if ever) we know the weight of individual marbles.  Surely one is expected to know the weight before moving a marble?  And the current weights of all bags??

Comment: The weights of individual marbles are known beforehand but algorithm doesn't depend on it. Same is for current weight of bags. For example, take any set of marbles and distribute them acros the bags such that weight of bags is between 400kg and 490Kg. So these are all known before run but algorithm should work if these are changed.